# How to assign to a variable the results of Find

Tags: c#, lambda, find

I want to assign a variable from a `Find` method.  Something like this:

```
object a = Collection.Find(x => x.propertie == whatever).propertie
```

The problem here is if my find query doesn't find anything.  I just wanted to know if there was a way to do it only with one line.

Comment: I wouldn't use Find(), but I don't see why that wouldn't find anything if you had the right conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is use LINQ to project your sequence of zero to n items into a property of that sequence.  This will only apply the projection if the item exists:

```
var a = collection.Select(x => x.Property)
    .FirstOrDefault(value => value == whatever);
```

Comment: The problem is I want to assign a propertie of the found object into a variable. If the Select Doesn't return an object. It won't work because null doesn't have the propertie i'm looking for.

Comment: @FrancisGroleau But it does work.  You're never trying to fetch a property from the default value.  The `Select` maps the sequence into a sequence of properties of the original elements.  If you have several items, you get the values of the relevant property.  If you have none, there are no items to apply the projection to.  You're never actually accessing a member of the default value here.

Comment: The only way I see it possible is if i initialize the object in the event of the Find request not returning anything something like :

    var a = collection.Find(x => x.Property == whatever).DefaultIfEmpty(new a{propertyA = null}).propertyA

Comment: @terrybozzio The whole point of this solution is that you don't *need* to use the conditional operator to check for null, because the projection is applied before the filter, and in such a way that it simply won't be applied even if the sequence is entirely empty.

Comment: @Servy yes lol i erased my comment when i saw firstordefault..sorry

Comment: @FrancisGroleau You certainly could do that.  Or you could do this.  Both solutions would work.  Personally I prefer this solution to yours.